# why is name of all threads same in python threading module?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading

```
from threading import *

def myfunc(i,name):
    print("This is " + str(name))

for i in range(4):
    name = current_thread().name
    t = Thread(target=myfunc, args=(i,name,))
    t.start()
```

---

`current_thread().getName()` also gives same results.I was wondering is this the way it works or is it running the same thread,so it is passing the the name `MainThread`?

---

**Output :** 
This is MainThread 
This is MainThread 
This is MainThread 
This is MainThread

Comment: `name = current_thread().name` You're always checking the name of the current thread, which is the main thread. You need to check `t.name`.

Comment: I suppose every time it enters the loop it creates the thread and current_thread().name should return its name.why is it returning the name `MainThread`

Comment: You're not calling that from the threads. You're only calling it from the main thread.

Comment: okay current_thread is the thread that is running the loop right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`current_thread()` always returns the thread that called `current_thread()`. You're repeatedly retrieving the name of the thread that's executing the loop, not the name of any of the threads that thread launches.

If you want to get the names of the threads launched in the loop, you could have *them* call `current_thread()`:

```
import threading

def target():
    print("This is", threading.current_thread().name)

for i in range(4):
    Thread(target=target).start()
```